# How to amend package.json when the package you are forking has been renamed?

Tags: git, npm, package, package.json, git-fork

A repository was forked and throughout the project I use its project name. Lets call it `packageInitial`. The original repo changed its name `packageChanged`. My `package.json` dependency looks like this:

```
"packageInitial": "git+https://github.com/organization/packageInitial.git#<HASH>",
```

If I update it to

```
"packageChanged": "git+https://github.com/organization/packageInitial.git#<HASH>",
```

nothing happens. The package is not installed in a folder called `packageChanged` under `node_modules`. My question is, how do I update the `package.json` file so that all someone has to do is `npm install` again and the package is installed and working?